# Firebase Phone Auth price

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase allow free 10k authentications/month + 0.06 per each extra authentication. I am reading a documentation however it is still not clear to me what authentication/validation definition is.

Does that mean I can receive 10k free sms messsages per month and I will pay nothing extra when user already logged in and uses APIs to call firebase services OR it means I will need to pay extra even after user successfully logged in but in case of firebase internally wants to validate authentication status as kind of a background task is considered authentication too?

In other words: let's say each month I have 10k new logins (sms received) should I expect to be charged anything extra?

Answer (score 5):

Firebase Auth only [charges on successful verification](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).
So if a user tries to sign in with a phone number and an SMS code is sent but not used or received by the user, this attempt will not be counted. Only when user enters the code and successfully verifies it (successfully signing in), will that attempt count. The first 10k successful verifications are free. Any successful verification afterwards will be $0.01/verification for US/Canada/India and $0.06/verification for other countries.

Comment: but as soon as user authorized and access firebase resources it is not considered to be authorization?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Auth will count verifications only. It doesn't track resource access.

Comment: thanks, this is what I meant, as soon as you are authenticated once the all following sessions to the resource is free?

Comment: Yes from Auth perspective. However if you are using some other Firebase service like realtime database, Firestore, etc. they have a different pricing scheme.

Answer (score 1):

There are few updates with Firebase Auth pricing as I received an email recently.

#### What do you need to know?

Significant changes in market conditions require more granular and variable pricing. Starting October 1, 2023, the following changes will be implemented:

- SMS (Short Message Service) usage will be charged for each sent SMS instead of each verified SMS.
- Variable per-region pricing will replace the current flat rate two tier pricing.
- Per-region pricing will update (at most) monthly.
- The free tier SMS limits will be 10 SMS-sent/day, replacing the current 10,000 SMS-verified/month.

[image]

#### What do you need to do?

With the new pricing model, you may start seeing SMS charges (for example, regions your app is not active in, or unrealistic volumes). We recommend you take the following steps to help protect your project from SMS traffic pumping and API abuse:

1. First, understand your regional SMS usage

- View your SMS usage and look for regions with a very high number of sent SMS and a very low number (or zero) of verified SMS. The ratio of verified/sent is your success rate. Healthy success rates are commonly in the 70-85% range since SMS is not a guaranteed delivery protocol, and some regions may experience abuse. Success rates below 50% imply many sent SMS but few successful logins, which is a common indicator of bad actors and SMS traffic pumping.

2. Consider setting an SMS Region Policy

- Use SMS Region Policy to either deny SMS regions with low success rates, or only allow certain regions if your app is only intended for distribution in certain markets.

3. Limit your authorized authentication domains

- Use the authentication settings dashboard to manage authorized domains. The localhost domain is added by default to the approved authentication domains to simplify development. You should consider removing localhost from the authorized domains in your production project to prevent bad actors from running code on their localhost to access your production project.

**Below are some additional options available if your project is upgraded to Identity Platform:**

**Enable and enforce App Check**

Enable App Check to help protect your project from API abuse by attesting that requests only come from applications associated with your project. Check Identity Platform pricing before upgrading, and remember that you will also need to enforce App Check for Authentication in the Firebase console (consider monitoring traffic before enforcing). Also, double check your reCAPTCHA Enterprise approved sites list to validate that it only contains your production sites, and that the list of applications registered to your project in App Check is accurate.

Note that App Check helps protect against automated attacks by asserting that the call comes from one of your registered applications. It does not prevent users from using your app in unintended ways (for example, starting then never finishing login flows to generate sent SMS).